# Catching an error while Spring injects a value

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

I'm using Spring to inject a GCP Secret into a variable, using the following code:

```kotlin
@Value("\${secret_name:{}}")
private lateinit var secretValue: String
```

In my `application.yaml` file I map `secret_name` to GCP's Secret Manager to a secret that doesn't necessarily exist (depending on the environment).

If this secret doesn't exist I get the following error, while trying to run my application:

> Application run failed
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name **<ServiceName>**: Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is com.google.api.gax.rpc.NotFoundException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: NOT_FOUND: Secret [projects/**<project_id>**/secrets/**<secret_name>**] not found or has no versions.

How can I catch this error while the `@Value` runs "behind the scenes"?

Comment: Not sure atm about catching that, especially since you have not mentioned what you want to happen after the error has been caught. But the quickest solution would be to use a default value. `@Value("${secret_name:not given}")` or something else, and then base your logic on that value, or have a check in the `init` of the class, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I do have `{}` as a default value, which doesn't work

Comment: Oh, just noticed. I'm not sure, I've never had that issue with default. Maybe that  `{}` is not an issue, but have you tried something else? Like `[]` or I don't know, `abc`. Just as a test, spring is fiddly sometimes, and maybe, just maybe it doesn't like the `{}` since those are already present in the declaration? It is a long shot, and maybe a silly attempt, but it might solve it.

Comment: The default will only work if `secret_name` doesn't exists, it doesn't work if the resolved `secret_name` doesn't exist. If you know it doesn't work in an environment use a different profile which has a hardcoded value for that secret (or omit the bean with with `@Profile` or something  like that.